# jQuery selector $.each not looping through all divs

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<div class="row-updated">
    <div>
        <span>Title</span>
        <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <span>Title</span>
        <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <span>Title</span>
        <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-updated">
    <div>
        <span>Title</span>
        <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to update the text in the second span for each div with class 'row-updated'.

```
var updated = $('.row-updated span:eq(1)');

$.each( updated, function( key, value ) {
    $(this).text('New text here');
});
```

But this does not seem to update all rows. It updates the first but not the second.

Comment: have you `$(document).ready(function(){ });` in your code?

Comment: Why the `.each()` iteration? jQuery returns an Object!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
var updated = $('.row-updated');

$.each( updated, function( key, value ) {
    $(this).find('span').eq(1).text('New text here');
});
```

Comment: This sounds like the correct solution, since OP wants to select the second span for each div. I do not understand why this was down-voted either.

Comment: If the span will always be followed by another span (like in html example), my answer would be best since generate less overhead. But if OP can't assure the spans will not be side by side, this answer is the most correct.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL what happens if OP adds a third span to each row-updated won't they be selected as well in your solution?

Comment: @YotamOmer Yup, third will as well (When evaluate on the first span, span + span would grab second. When evaluate on the second span, span + span would grab third). That's why I said *"will always be followed by another span (like in html example)"*. If he can't assure the example html, then yours is the best :)

Comment: @RaphaelDDL you could always use `span:first-child + span`

Answer (score 3):

`.eq()` doesn't do what you think it does. You need to use `.nth-child()` here.

```
// nth-child() is 1-indexed as @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ  pointed out in the comment (thanks!).
var updated = $('.row-updated span:nth-child(2)');

$.each( updated, function( key, value ) {
    $(this).text('New text here');
});
```

`.eq` will return the `nth` element out of the *whole* set of results, not the nth `span`.

Comment: nth-child isn't 0 indexed :P

Answer (score 2):

`:eq()` filters the entire jQuery collection of the `.row-updated span` selector.

Use this selector:

```
var updated = $('.row-updated span + span');

$.each( updated, function( key, value ) {
    $(this).text('New text here');
});
```

*Explanation of selector:*
This selector grabs the `span` which is followed by another `span` inside `.row-updated`.

I think will run faster than actually using `.find().eq()` from the other answer since it's less function overhead (it's a css selector only).

Of course considering the second span is followed by the first or else you will need `find` and `eq`.

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/TDLBA/)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, because all answers still have that `.each()`...

You don't need the implicit iteration because jQuery is able to return a jQuery object.

So you can use:

```
var allMySecondSpans = $('.row-updated div span:nth-child(2)'); // Or 1 of the other ways
allMySecondSpans.text('New text here');
```